# Ionic side-menu toggle event

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am develoing an `ionic` application(2.1.4)under `cordova`.
The codes are like below.I need to trigger a function after closed the `side menu`.Shortly, a `change event`.Is it possible to implement `side menu` to catch these events? Or do you have any suggestion to solve this?

```
<ion-menu side="left" [content]="mycontent" >
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>DENEME</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
     <ion-list-header>Items</ion-list-header>

      <ion-item *ngFor="let it of items">
          <ion-label>{{it.name}}</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox color="secondary" checked="{{it.checked}}"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  <ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
  <ion-nav  #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `(ionClose)`:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" (ionOpen)="menuOpened()" (ionClose)="menuClosed()">
```

When the menu closes, the `menuClosed()` function will fire.

Comment: its all the way at the bottom at output events...it doesnt really pop out at u just 3 words in a list